# Rails 4 ActiveRecord Relationships issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am setting up an application and I am having issues with ActiveRecord relationships. here is the breakdown.

**1. A Client has_many Sites therefore a Site belongs_to Client**

```
class Client
 has_many :sites
end

class Site
 belongs_to :client
end
```

**2. A Site has_many Reports therefore a Report belongs_to Site**

```
class Site
 has_many: reports
end

class Report
 belongs_to :site
end
```

3. this is where I am getting stumped.

   A Patrol has_many Hits therefore a Hit belongs_to Patrol

   A Hit belongs_to Site therefore a Site has_many Hits

   a Report belongs_to Site therefore a Site has_many Reports

the problem is setting this last part up not too sure to to layout the models or if a :through relationship is warranted?? Essentially what I am hoping to achieve here is that when an admin sets up a patrol and assigns a site to a hit the user can view the site through the hit show page and generate a new site report than can then be viewed under the client/site show page in the admin table.?

Am I out in outer-space here??

Nesting the client and site was a breeze and i can generate a new report from the site show page, but to streamline report creation for the end user I am hoping to go the above route.. just not sure about how to proceed.

If you require further assistance please let me know ill give you what I can!

Thanks.

EDIT # 1 My Model Structure

```
This group is nested as a site is built through the client show page
class Client
 has_many :sites
end 

class Site
 belongs_to :client
end
```

> This is where I am having the most troubel, as there is alot going on
>   here at least in my mind. I am open to any suggestions in configuring
>   this..

```
class PatrolRoute
 has_many :patrol_hits
end

class PatrolHit
 belongs_to :patrol_route
# A PatrolHit Should only have one Site and that site should not be created only selected from a dropdown box of pre-existing sites
end

class Site
belongs_to :patrol_hit
has_many: patrol_reports
end

Class PatrolReport
belongs_to :site
has_many :line_items
end 

class LineItem 
 belongs_to :report
end
```

Comment: what is `Patrol`? another model?

Comment: ill add all of my models

Comment: I just ask about `Patrol`. It's anotger model or instance of some model listed here?

Comment: No as of right not it is nothing Patrol is Patrol Route Now

Comment: I added a better model breakdown for you to review

Comment: @Aleksey any thoughts?

Comment: `PatrolHit` could have `has_one :site`, couldn't it?

Comment: Ill give it a try it should.. thats what i am wanting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124373/discussion-between-aleksey-and-shawn-wilson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to provide you with exact answer since the whole thing and DB structure are unclear.

One thing that might help you to deal with all those associations is simple:
`belongs_to :foo` means that model's DB table should have `foo_id` column.

In your particular case

```
class PatrolHit
  belongs_to :patrol_route
end
```

means that `patrol_hits` table should have columns like

```
id             
patrol_route_id
...
```

I think keeping that rule in mind would help you.